# Adding string to int32 column in datatable

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

I am pretty sure this is not possible but I will ask for clarification.

I am using ExcelLibrary in C# to convert a dataset into an Excel document. I recently had the requirement to add a string to the end of the excel document in every file. I simply added two new rows to the datatable (one empty and the second row displayed the string in the first cell).

I got a bug report today because in one particular excel document the first column displays the ID (something unusual in the system) and I get the error:

```
Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <**mystring**> in id Column.  Expected type is Int32.
```

I am pretty sure I cannot add my string to this column and I need to add it to a different column which is a nvarchar, but does anyone have any suggestions to resolve this problem?

edit: the code for anyone who may require it

```
DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow(); 
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr); 
DataRow dr2 = ds.Tables[0].NewRow(); 
dr2[0] = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["excelString"];
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr2);
```

The dataset I am working with is directly from a query in the database and the first column is an INT

Comment: Paste your code please

Comment: @CarlosLanderas I have added the code as requested

Comment: On which line you get this error?

Comment: @SonerGönül the last line. When I add the excelString to the dataset it throws an exception giving the error you can read above.

Comment: @James I don't understand. You have no `excelString` or `dr2[0]` in your last line. Did you debug your code? What are your values? Which operation throws this _Input string was not in a correct format_?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?